# How can chunks be allocated in a node.js stream in object mode all at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, stream

I can see how buffers, and strings can be sent as chunks, but I'm having a problem thinking about how streams can be dealt when working in object mode.

Say I have a byte stream from an http request message. I want to take that message, parse, and then transform it into one big object.

I already know how to parse the message. What I'm wondering is if the message is big so it has many chunks, but I want to make one object for the output how can I make sure the data event waits for the whole thing?

Is this just a matter of not using the push method until the chunked data has finished being sent?

That would then restrict the stream data output to a smaller object which I think I'm fine with for now.

As an added condition the larger data will be reduced in size after the the transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your transform stream only ever outputs one object, then all you have to do is just `push()` the object from your `_flush()` implementation.

Comment: Actually I just learned that the chunk from a request is the length of the body so that may be the solution to what I was asking. I was assuming that a request might have more than one chunk. Which was the problem I was having. If I want one object output from my transform how do I deal with multiple chunks from a pipe from request? I hadn't yet had the problem so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Also thanks. I was thinking flush would be it since I have read that it is called after transform. Can you add something about that to your answer for clarity?

Comment: You would either buffer the multiple chunks or do some kind of partial parsing in your `_transform()`. You should also use `_flush()` just in case you do receive more than one chunk during the lifetime of the stream. `_flush()` is called right before 'end' is emitted on the stream.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be looking at flush.